# Using buttonIndex with multiple alert views

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have about 4 alert views with different criteria when they appear. In all 4 views, the right button should always do the same thing.

I use the code below to try and say IF the buttonIndex == 1, do something.

Currently, It only works in one of my alert views. The others just end up closing the alert view and never running the code for IF buttonIndex == 1.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
if (a==1) {
            NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                             @"Only $%@!",dollas.text];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                              @"Really?!"

                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [message release];

        }

else if (a==2) {
            NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                 @"Somone just paid you $%@", dollas.text];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                                  @"Swish!"

                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            [message release];

        }
```

And the delegate:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
       do.stuff;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `buttonIndex == 1`. Instead, use `buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex` or `buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex`.

Comment: Oh nice. Didnt know I could do that. Thanks

Comment: If the only difference between each alert is the title and message then use variables for those and then have one set of code that creates and displays the alert view. No sense repeating the same code over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be setting the delegate to `self` so that method gets called.

IE -

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                      @"Really?!"

                                                message:message
                                               delegate:self //SELF
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the tags on each alertview and inside -didDismissWithButtonIndex check first for the alerts tag

eg:

```
    if (a==1) {
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                         @"Only $%@!",dollas.text];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                          @"Really?!"

                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",nil];
    alert.tag = 1;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [message release];

    }
    else if (a==2) {
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                             @"Somone just paid you $%@", dollas.text];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                              @"Swish!"

                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",nil];
        alert.tag = 2;
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [message release];

    }
```

then in -didDismissWithButtonIndex

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1 && actionSheet.tag == 1)
    {
       do.stuff;
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1 && actionSheet.tag == 2)
    {
       do.otherStuff;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I actually needed to change the delegate:nil to delegate:self in the UIAlertViews

Answer (score 2):

For the case (a == 2) you set the `UIAlertView` delegate to nil, so `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` shouldn't even be getting called for this case. Change it to set the delegate to self.